# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar la interfaz gráfica de ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

¿Como puedo recuperar el arranque de mi sistema ubuntu 16.04?

Tengo instalado Ubuntu 16.04 con una tarjeta gráfica AMD 470, el problema es que hice una actualización por medio de la terminal y ahora no me deja arrancar el sistema; primero me salió un mensaje de que el sistema estaba corriendo en gráficos bajos y podía entrar a las **tty**, vi una supuesta solución que me resultó peor que fue usar el comando `apt-get install gdm` y ahora en cualquier **tty** parpadea y no me deja teclear nada.

Ojala me puedan ayudar.

saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Trata de instalar de nuevo el entorno gráfico, prueba con:

```
apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```